# Parse IP from text then ping IP

Tags: parsing, ip, ping

can you share to me a Python program where I need to parse the IP only from series of text and ping the IP's

text file:

IP Address: x.x.x.x  with subnet: x.x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python solution:

```
    #This is a program to read a file and ping the IP address found in the first line of
import subprocess
#IP Address: x.x.x.x with subnet: x.x.x.x
file = open("file.txt", "r")
fileContent = file.read()
# now parsing the file
fileSplitted = fileContent.split()
ipAddress = fileSplitted[2]
print(ipAddress)
subprocess.Popen(["ping", ipAddress])
```